# How do I get crystallize filter effect with the Blender compositor

Tags: effects, blur, compositing-nodes

I'm new to the compositor and I'm trying to achieve this effect:
[image]

a little close up

[image]

I have tried using the pixelate, blur and directional blur nodes but the effect isn't the same, btw I got the example using the Crystallize filter in Photoshop

Comment: This effect doesn't look anything like blurry effect, nor pixelate.The fact that this looms a bit like a clay effect, i think it may be quite hard to achieve in the blender compositor.

Comment: Please don't add [SOLVED] to the title of the question, it's not necessary - you already marked an answer as correct. Check https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers to learn more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try using Blender's Displace node fed with a Voronoi texture. If the displacement is to rough then apply some gentle blur also driven by the texture.

[image: voronoi displacement to simulate crystalize]

To achieve the daubed paint effect I have added a Bilateral blur node to constrain the blur. I feed this with a mixture of the source image and the Voronoi texture.

[image: Daub blur]

[image: displacement texture source]

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you very much!, that is exactly the effect I was looking for!

Comment: Yay! Keep in mind that there are a bunch of variables in there to tweak to get the right balance between blur and detail as well as crystal size/distortion.